# In flux, why Store is needed?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

According to [Flux Architecture](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) View uses Action to call Dispatcher that updates the Store, while View listening to Store change events.

My question is: Why do we need Store?

In order to list all users, my Component will call ListAllUsersAction that will in turn call my API and will update the Store with the result of API call. Store then emits change event that the View is listening to. But the store also stores the result. Why? Why this middle layer is needed? I wont call the store directly anyway, so this cache layer makes no sense to me, and as I generate more events that loads more data, eventually all my stores will have all the state of my application because flux architecture says nothing about cleaning the Stores.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The purpose of Flux Store is keeping data that need to be shared across multiple components. If no components needs that data except one and data will not be transformed — no store is required.

Comment: Ok, let me elaborate a bit more. Lets say Posts are needed only in one component: PostList. According to your answer I wont need PostStore in such case. When my PostList component is loaded it call LoadAllPostsAction but ti whom the Action emits? Component can not listen to Actions, because the flow is then broken. It should be Component -> Action -> Store -> Component and this closes the uni-directional data flow. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've just come across [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/pZYYbyOHKCs) that should help clarify things, mainly the  4th and 5th posts.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of Flux is to keep data flow easy to understand even as apps becomes large and complex, such that a new person can be brought up to speed quickly, figure out what's going on by inspecting the source code, and be confident that they can make changes without breaking things. Modularity and separation of concerns are a big part of that. The Stores are a way to keep the data models independent of the details of the view layer and establish a single source of truth for the application state. You can look at any Store's code and see what data it holds, what actions it responds to, which dependencies it has for data in other Stores. It's a matter of organization for the sake of the developers, at the cost of code being slightly less compact.

> In order to list all users, my Component will call ListAllUsersAction
>   that will in turn call my API and will update the Store with the
>   result of API call.

Since the function of Actions is mainly to provide updated data to stores, you could also just call the API first and then just create one Action to handle the result.

> as I generate more events that loads more data, eventually all my
>   stores will have all the state of my application because flux
>   architecture says nothing about cleaning the Stores.

Holding the *current* state of the application is the intended function of the Stores. If user actions or API calls cause the data to change, the Actions notify the Stores and the Stores responsible for keeping that data update accordingly (maybe even being reset to null). There's no need for any other sort of cleaning, because the Stores "having all the state" is exactly what they're supposed to be doing.

Comment: I've created a chat room for the question. I'd be glad if you could join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70619/flux-architecture-and-the-purpose-of-stores

Answer (score 1):

Stores are in charge of application state and logic, so for example, let's say you fetch all users through your `ListAllUsersAction`, you get an array from your API

```
var users = [{firstName: 'LIMELIGHTS'}, {firstName: 'SKWEE357'}];
```

Now, the users name are apparently capitalised as your API decides that this is the way to deliver the data.

This just won't do so you want to fix it.
Using just React or just the Action where would you put this code, where would it make sense?
In your view, your dispatcher or your action? No, you definitely don't want to clutter your React component with this type of logic.
Nor does it make sense to do this data manipulation in the Dispatcher or Action, they are after all just notifiers that something should happen.

Comment: Good point, but this does not answer the follow question: I've visited Users page, UserListComponent called ListAllUsersAction that populated UsersStore that emitted event that UserListComponent is subscribed to. All good: now the store has users data as well as the component (data duplication?). I then navigate to another page that initiates similar flow, then another and another and eventually, since the store is never purged, the client will have all the application state. Who is responsible to clean the stores?

Comment: Oh and another question :let's say component A and component B listens to user store changes, but component A list users in lowercase and B lists them in upper case. What type of data the store should hold?

Comment: It's not data duplication because the component isn't managing its own competing copy of the data, it's just pulling the data it needs from the Store. When the user navigates to different pages, you could choose to keep the previous data (maybe they'll go back and expect it to still be there) or you could fire off Actions in `componentWillUnmount` to set it to null. Display details like uppercase vs lowercase should be established in the views, the text can be stored however you like.

Comment: Adam, it is. Components state reflects the state of the store at some point in time. Once the store is updated, the components state updates as well. If I clean the store on unmount, I might break the state of the app because other components might still need the data in the store. It looks to me that Flux is a nice architecture for simple, demo like application, where there is one store (like todo app example), and it's not really scales well enough for real, complex applications.

Comment: @skwee357 Of course it's data duplication, as soon as someone is aware of other data it's data duplication but not in the sense that the component clones the data. If you ever unmount a store you should always unmount the components that listen to that store too, it goes without saying. Furthermore, the data passed down from stores are in props and not in state. React and Flux is definitely mature for real complex applications, (we built our product on it).

Comment: @limelights Ok, makes sense. But how I can unmount a store? Who is responsible for unmounting a stores? Lets try some real examples I'm struggling with. I have a list of users. I have 2 components: One shows active users the other shows banned users. Should they use the same store? If so, what data does each of them requests from the store? LoadActiveUsersAction for ActiveUsersComponent and LoadBannedUsersAction for BannedUsersComponent? Or they both request the full users list and then filter out what is irrelevant?

Comment: Flux is a nice concept but it has a lot of un-answered questions. How do you do API calls: in actions or in stores? Who clean the stores? If you clean the store on component unmount, you no longer have decoupled architecture because the cleaning component should know whether other components are listening and need the data. And essentially: What is a store exactly? If I have User entity, should I have Users Store? Or store for Active Users and Banned Users? And if I add more components like "users who logged in the past 7 days" should I create a corresponding store to such entities?

Comment: @limelights i've created a chat room on this question to avoid long feed of comments. I'd be glad if you could join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70619/flux-architecture-and-the-purpose-of-stores